# How can I create a directory symbolic link on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2003, symbolic-link

I'm trying to create a directory symbolic link under Windows Server 2003 but I'm not having any luck.

I've tried junction.exe (Sysinternals), ln.exe, and linkd.exe (Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit).

I'd like **c:\folder\subfolder** to link to **\fileserver\realSubfolder**

This works perfectly fine under Windows 7 (using mklink.exe) but I can't get this to work under Windows Server 2003.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP are very similar, so maybe some of these will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90121/symlink-in-windows-xp

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Directory symlinks were introduced in Windows Vista. The closest analog is directory reparse points (aka junctions), which the Systinternals Junction tool you referenced can create.

Comment: Are you sure?  I'm looking at the Sysinternals page for Junction.exe (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) and it says that "Windows 2000 and higher supports directory symbolic links"?

Comment: I think that's just a conflict in terminology. Reparse points used to be the closest thing Windows had to symbolic links, until they added a new feature actually called symbolic links in Vista. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#Microsoft_Windows

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is that the group policy doesn't allow you to use directory symbolic links on network paths, for security reasons.

Check it here: `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\NTFS File System\Selectively Allow The Evaluation Of A SymbolicLink`

Answer (score 1):

Junctions won't support UNC paths. It only resolves for local paths.

Junctions are a subset of reparse points, so the same restriction applies also.

Starting with Vista, you can create symlinks, which will resolve to a remote path. They will even let you daisy chain symlinks with remote paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can, please see my response to this similar question over at stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18593425/18475